# SabreAMF: PHP Integer array to Java Integer List

Tags: java, php

I am using SabreAMF to call on a Java webservice.

This is the Java function:

```
@RemotingInclude
public Boolean testAMF(List<Integer> ints)
{
    for (Integer element : ints) 
    {  
        //do something
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note that this function accepts a List of Integers.

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
    require 'SabreAMF/Client.php';

    function make_request($service, $method, $params)
    {
        $client = new SabreAMF_Client('https://xxx');
        return $client->sendRequest($service.'.'.$method,$params);
    }

    $ints = array(1,2);
    $parameters = array($ints);
    $result = make_request('chartManager','testAMF',$parameters);
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

I pass along an array containing 2 integers.
In Java, this array comes in as a list, but one containing Doubles, not ints.

I then get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException : java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Why does it change my integer to a double ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only Doubles in [AMF0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format). So you need to change the type to `Double`.

You can get integer support if you use AMF3:

```
    $client = new SabreAMF_Client('https://xxx');
    $client->setEncoding(SabreAMF_Const::AMF3);
    return $client->sendRequest($service.'.'.$method,$params);
```